# How to design/build the electronic part of a hybrid (liquid + electronic) multi tube manometer

Tags: arduino, sensor, circuit-design, component-selection

I am in the early stages of designing/building a multi tube manometer for a DIY wind tunnel.

For those not familiar with what a manometer is, it's a pressure measuring device, and looks something similar to this:

[image: multi tube manometer]

I have the hardware part designed, but I want to automate the data collection part. Instead of periodically manually taking readings of heights of the various columns (tubes), I want to be able to able to do that electronically.

In the olden days, the (pressure) data was obtained by taking photographs of the column heights, and then later, plotting that to an aerfoil shape - I want to eliminate that step (since it's too error prone) - and directly fetch the data from the device, using electronics.

I am thinking of using an Arduino board as the microcontroller, but can't yet thing of how to harvest the liquid height information from the device.

What's the best way of electronically capturing the height data from said multi tube manometer?

**[[ UPDATE ]]**

The fluid inside the tube will be distilled water, and I cannot insert any sensors in the tubes as they may affect the airflow characteristics of the airfoil I'm testing

Comment: I'm confused. How would a sensor in the tube impact the reading? If it was in the test area it would have an impact but we are talking about in a sensor tube away from the test chamber. I can see it impacting the dynamic response but it shouldn't impact the final pressure any more than a change in width or join in the pipe would. Hardly my area of expertise so I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just curious as to the mechanism by which it would impact the results.

Comment: You know you can get direct digital air pressure measurement sensors? That might be considerably easier.

Comment: @Andrew Flexible tubing will be attached directly from holes drilled in the airfoil, to the manometer tubes. Any obstructions in the tubing or manometer tube (e.g. a sensor), may affect the airflow over the airfoli at that point (for e.g. the "obstruction" could create small eddies etc.)

Comment: @pjc50 That would be preferable, but I couldn't find any that seemed to be applicable to what I wanted to do (and for a sensible price). If you know of any such product, please post a link here, so I may check it out.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli That still doesn't make sense to me. The tube is a dead end, the air inside it is static except when the pressure is changing. When the pressure is changing there will be a small air flow due to the fluid level moving and the gas compressing/decompressing. How can a static element inside the tube change this? How would it create small eddies in the test chamber but the moving fluid level not have any impact?

Comment: @Andrew I understand what you're saying - BUT, my point is that when there is a change in pressure, this will cause air to flow in the tube. Any body immersed in that airflow WILL change the aerodynamics of the aiflow (even if marginally). I could I suppose, calibrate for the presence of a body in the airflow - but I want to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: Possible sensor: http://uk.farnell.com/measurement-specialties/ms563702ba03-50/sensor-barometric-0-01-1-2bar/dp/2362663 (if that's not applicable, specify your pressure range and desired resolution)

Comment: @pjc50 Funnily enough, shortly after I messaged you, I did a quick, more refined search, and came up with a sensible product from farnell as well!. I may just go for that, instead of rolling my own! Even though, it would be cool if I could build my own (trying to learn how to do these things on my own!) - if it seems like too much work (from answers submitted), I'll cop out and just buy off the shelf though .

Comment: Why not just use a semiconductor pressure sensor in each chamber?  Cheap, easy, and accurate

Comment: @pjc50 That sensor has an error of +/- 2mBar at room temperature. 1mBar is about 1cm of water. So using that sensor would be about the same as a 2cm error in the measurement on each tube. That may well be good enough for this application but if he is worried about the impact of a non-perfect tube in the readings (but oddly not about moving liquid) then I'm guessing he's aiming for better than 2cm accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Mercury (Hg shown in picture in question) is 62 times less conductive than silver (the best ambient conductor) but you can still induce significant eddy currents in it so, for each tube, encircle with a coil (a solenoid). With no mercury present the inductance will be (say) high and progressively, as mercury rises in the tube, the inductance will lower due to eddy currents in the liquid conducting metal.

Use the TI inductance measurement chip: -

[image]

[image]

Even salty water could be measured using this method I reckon.

Comment: This is an interesting idea ... especially more so, if I can use salty water. I can't use Hg; I am running the experiment from my garage, and I wouldn't even know how to acquire it (if even I did, it may raise security red flags - with all the terrorism that's going on ...).

If you have any more information (e.g. links) on using this method with salty water please enlighten me.

Comment: The only info I can realistically give on using salty water is that there will be eddy currents (due to conductivity of salty water) and these will change the inductance slightly but more importantly, it will take energy from the solenoid and dissipate as small amounts of heat - this is quite easily detected and food-grade metal detectors are easily "tripped" when there is too much salt content in a foodstuff. I think it's an easy thing to build to get started and you could just use a Wein bridge oscillator with the inductor as part of the tuned components. You should see amplitude......

Comment: .... degradation as well as a frequency shift proportional to the amount of salty water but, because the salt density is not as defined as a homogeneous material like mercury, there will be a calibration cycle involved.

Answer (score 0):

What is the liquid? Is it conductive?
Is it possible to put devices into the tubes or must this be done externally?

The simple methods that spring to mind are either an ultrasound sensor in the top of the tube measuring the distance to the liquid surface or some form of resistive wire lowered into a conductive liquid with a second electrode either in the reservoir or the other side of the tube. As the liquid moves up and down the tube the resistance between the two contacts will change.

You could also do it optically, the simple way would be a series of lights and detectors, by seeing which light beams are broken you know the height. This has the disadvantage of having discrete steps in the measurement. Going high tech you could use a camera and some image processing to detect the top of the liquid in the tubes.
Or you could go with a partly mechanical system, a single optical source/detector that is mechanically moved up and down the tube and finds the point where the light is blocked.

Getting more whimsical, just as the tone produced by a wine glass changes with the amount of liquid in the glass the liquid would change the resonance of the tubes. If you induced a high frequency vibration in the tube and measured the response this could be translated into a liquid level.

My first choice would be the ultrasound based system, it's simple, low tech and  non-contact. Assuming the pressures are all fairly close to 1 atmosphere the errors caused by the pressure dependency of the speed of sound should be minimal and can be controlled for, temperature would probably be a bigger impact on accuracy and is easy to measure and correct for if needed. The big issue is whether it's practical to implement from a physical point of view.

Comment: please see my updated question.

Comment: Don't forget to apply end correction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_correction